# Как фиксировать IsMouseOver над элементом ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

### Исходные данные

Есть ListBox. Структура его элементов задаётся ItemTemplate. При выборе одного из элементов совершается действие (меняется содержимое окна). Среди прочего, у каждой строки списка есть кнопки, изначально скрытые.

### Задача

При наведении курсора на элемент списка, его кнопки должны становиться видимыми. Если возможно, не выходя за пределы паттерна MVVM, не прибегая к code-behind.

### Решения и проблемы

#### 1

С помощью триггера у меня получилось связать кнопку со свойством IsMouseOver родительского контейнера (Border или DockPanel).

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Name="Item" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        
                        <Button Content="Btn"
                                Height="30" FontSize="20"
                                BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Item}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Всё работает как надо, но только пока курсор касается текста или рамки, пустое пространство внутри того же Border не активирует триггер.

[image: Border Name="Item"]

#### 2

Эту проблему решает помещение Border в ListBoxItem и обращение триггера кнопки к нему.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem Name="Item">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                        //Всё то же самое
                    </Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Я ожидал тем самым обратиться к контейнеру самого верхнего уровня для элемента списка, но вместо этого WPf создаёт прозрачный прямоугольник, перекрывающий вложенные элементы. При наведении на него курсора триггер кнопки работает достаточно хорошо, но клик по нему не приводит к выбору элемента списка.

[image: ListBoxItem Name="Item"]

Обратите внимание, что размер созданного ListBoxItem прямоугольника не совпадает с фактическим размером элемента списка.

#### Вопросы

Как заставить свойсто IsMouseOver контейнеров считывать курсор над вложенным пустым пространством?

Как обратиться к контейнеру верхнего уровня, используя ItemTemplate?

Comment: Первый пример у вас не работает потому, что нет заливки у бордера, даже прозрачной, установите ее, например так: `Background="Transparent"` и будет реагировать на всю область, а не только текст и рамки. Но это еще не все, скорей всего вы будете терять фокус в момент наведения мыши на кнопку, если так, то тут наверно стоит мульти триггер делать, который проверит `IsMouseOver` бордера и кнопки. Во втором случае попробуйте кнопке задать `Panel.ZIndex`, но проблему с потерей `IsMouseOver` при наведении на кнопку это не решит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот уж не думал, что указание `Background` так влияет на поведение. Я был уверен, что `Background="Transparent"` стоит у контейнеров по умолчанию. Благодарю.

Comment: Нет, по умолчанию там `x:Null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так получится. Убрал лишнее, немного поправил разметку. Не используйте `Label` в WPF, это устаревшее наследие. Используйте `TextBlock` для отображения текста. Не используйте размеры, используйте отступы.

```xml
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Btn" Padding="15,5"
                            FontSize="20"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="Transparent">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

> Как обратиться к контейнеру верхнего уровня, используя `ItemTemplate`?

См. `RelativeSource`

Comment: Это именно то, что я так долго искал, благодарю. А почему `DockPanel` заменили на `Grid`? Где вообще можно почитать, какие элементы являются устаревшим наследием, а какие надо использовать?

Comment: @Kram в целом это касается только `Label`, а `Grid` проще управляема. `DockPanel` тоже специфичная штука, я с ней навоевался, есть куча более простых альтернатив, и одна из них - обычный `Grid`.