# ListBoxItem styl wpf смена фона

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь поменять фон элемента ListBox.
XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
           <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Данный код не работает, НО! Если переключить `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">` на `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">` то фон меняется!

Также было попробовано решение:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="Part_Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <!--Triggers-->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Part_Border" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Part_Border" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Но оно также не решило проблему! Пример его работы снизу:

Курсор тут(красненький) триггер не работает! Хотя курсор находится на item'е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Курсор на элементе item'а, триггер работает! Он также находится на item'е!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В стандартном компоненте ListBox триггер срабатывает по всей поверхности item'a!

Необходимо решение, которое будет реагировать на триггер Item так же как и стандартный ListBox!
Я уже не знаю что делать, элементарный вопрос, но в инете ответов нет! Может где то можно достать стиль полностью стандартного ListBox и поменять все как надо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62352677/12888024

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1474137/373567

Answer (score 2):

Тебе лучше переписать шаблон ListBoxItem. К сожалению, так, как ты хочешь, не сработает. Прикладываю простой вариант шаблона стиля для ListBoxItem:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="Part_Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <!--Triggers-->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Part_Border" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Part_Border" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Ну и в самом ListBox не забудь этот стиль вставить:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

Comment: закинул этот код в App.xaml, попытался вставить стиль в ListBox через Style='{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}' и ничего. Ошибка Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка XDG0062 TargetType "ListBoxItem" не соответствует типу элемента "ListBox".

Comment: решение не работает!

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER Вам нужно не в Style для ListBox это вставлять, а для ItemContainerStyle у ListBox, ведь мы пишем стиль не для ListBox, а для его item-ов, а этот стиль находится в свойстве ItemContainerStyle

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER для прозрачности, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Не обратил внимание! попробую

Comment: Это решение не подходит. Триггер работает лишь тогда, когда я взаимодействую с одной из элементов контейнера. То-есть если я наведусь на item в котором будет пустой элемент - он не отреагирует.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER что значит item в котором будет пустой элемент? В вопросе нет ничего про это, в таком случае предоставляйте полный пример с нужной вам логикой. Данный код делает то, что ожидается.

Comment: то и значит. если у нас есть коллекция в которой все item'ы пустые, то ListBox выведет все item'ы но с вашим кодом триггеры работать не будут.  Триггер срабатывает не по item'у в целом, а по его элементам. Данный код не делает, то что ожидается. Он очень странно работает и это претензия не к вам.

Comment: проверьте свой код.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER и все-же, я не понимаю, что значит пустой item. Код меняет background свойство у listboxitem, listboxitem - это элемент коллекции listbox.itemssource. Если вы работаете с биндингом к коллекции, то каждый элемент коллекции = listboxitem его отображения.  Т.е. вопрос такой, чем отличается item о котором вы пишите от элемента? Даже с английского перевода - это так и переводится. Какой эффект вы пытаетесь получить?

Comment: я пытаюсь поменять стандартный триггер на наведение и нажатие по элементу ListBox'а, у него меняется фон и обводка при взаимодействии с полной областью item'а. не знаю как вам ещё донести, что мне нужно =)

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER и все же, что такое item и элемент у ListBox?

Comment: Источником данных для компонентка ListBox является его свойство ItemSource, куда мы кладем нашу коллекцию. Отвечаю на ваш вопрос - Item это один из объектов в коллекции ItemSource, а элемент - это один из элементов в ListBox.ItemTemplate.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER понятно. ListBoxItem - это визуальный элемент представления данных. Кол-во таких item-ов равно кол-ву элементов в ItemsSource (почти всегда). Теперь можно вернуться к основному вопросу. Что вы ожидаете увидеть, когда наводите мышью на ListBoxItem. Данный код полностью меняет background-цвет для ListBoxItem-а именно его, цельно. Т.е. переопределяется стандартный цвет. Если вы хотите менять цвет не у всего элемента, а у скажет TextBox, который находится внутри этого визуального представления, то это уже совсем другая история. Опять же я считаю что вопрос составлен не корректно.

Comment: вы не понимаете, сейчас скрины отправлю..........

Comment: дополнил вопрос, с примером.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER понятно, вам нужно задать стандартный background - в вашем случае это transparent

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER я изменил xaml стиль, попробуйте такой...

Comment: спасибо! пробую